# Set angular object value to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to generate a random image each time an angular object is added. In my html, I say:

```
<img ng-src="{{posts.img}}">
```

However, in the url field it's returning
     `%7B%22url%22:%22https://i.pinimg.com/originals/23/4f/2f/234f2fe11f1a71b058ab19d9a3d0801a.jpg%22%7D`

rather than just the image url. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my js:

```
    $scope.addPost = function() {
      var url;
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        if (num === 1) url = "https://uproxx.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/creedbratton-creedthoughts-1.gif?w=650";
        else if (num === 2) url = "https://i.imgur.com/90akEXq.gif";
        else if (num === 3) url = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/23/4f/2f/234f2fe11f1a71b058ab19d9a3d0801a.jpg";

      $scope.posts.push({
        title:$scope.formContent,
        upvotes:0,
        comments:[],
        img:{url}      //this is what I'm having trouble with
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
    $scope.posts.push({
        title:$scope.formContent,
        upvotes:0,
        comments:[],
        img:url      //this is what I'm having trouble with
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea however in your HTML I assume you are trying to iterate over your posts, however it looks like you are accessing a attribute from the array directly.

As of right now you have :

```
<img ng-src="{{posts.img}}">
```

Shouldn't this be accessing an element of the array? For example:

```
<img ng-src="{{posts[0].img}}">
```

Also you are pushing an object with a url attribute into the img attribute. You have:

```
 $scope.posts.push({
        title:$scope.formContent,
        upvotes:0,
        comments:[],
        img:{url}      <-----
    });
```

But really you should not be wrapping it in the `{}` (remove the {})

```
 $scope.posts.push({
            title:$scope.formContent,
            upvotes:0,
            comments:[],
            img:url      <-----
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable `url` and you are adding it to `$scope.post` object by `img:{url}`. But in reality, you are adding an object `{url: urlValue}` to `img` key.

You need to either modify the value of `img` key like `img:url`. Then, your code will be

```
 $scope.posts.push({
    title:$scope.formContent,
    upvotes:0,
    comments:[],
    img:url
});
```

Then you can access image url using `<img ng-src="{{posts.img}}">`

In case you still want to store the image url in an object.

```
$scope.posts.push({
    title:$scope.formContent,
    upvotes:0,
    comments:[],
    img:{url}
});
```

Then you can access image url as `<img ng-src="{{posts.img.url}}">`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your HTML, you have a typo, and the code should have been this:

```
<img ng-src="{{posts[0].img}}">
```

The problem is with this block of the code:

```
img:{url}
```

`{url}` is EcmaScript [shorthand property synatax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) which is valid in all the modern browsers. Due to this behaviour, the code becomes something like this:

```
img: {
  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/90akEXq.gif'
}
```

And in your code, you're referring to the key `img` in `ng-src`, which actually stringifies and URL encodes this:

```
{
  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/90akEXq.gif'
}
```

to this:

```
%7Burl:%20'https://i.imgur.com/90akEXq.gif'%7D

// encodeURI(JSON.stringify(posts[0].img));
```

Hence, you see this malformed string in your HTML. To resolve this, you need to change your HTML to this:

```
<!-- img.url returns the URL string, instead of the object -->
<img ng-src="{{posts[0].img.url}}">
```